# How we can ignore NDB cached query result?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a model called SignupTokens, we are updating entity with isUsed = True when user is confirm their from our chatbot, after updating entity if we query for not used token for specific same email with isUsed = False then some time result is back even there were isUsed flag already updated with True. We have double check in datastore entity is single at the time whenever we are facing this problem.

```
SignupTokens.gql("where isUsed = :1 and email = :2",False,email).get()
```

We have already try to use_cache = False like

```
SignupTokens.gql("where isUsed = :1 and email = :2",False,email).get(use_cache=False)
```

Pls let me know any one has idea about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely not an ndb caching problem, it's the expected datastore behaviour due to [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#nosql-and-eventual-consistency): it will take some time from the moment an entity's `isUsed` property is set to `True` until the index corresponding to your query is updated accordingly.

Until the index is updated the query results *will not reflect the change*.

Comment: Okay, is there any way to we can confirm is datastore and index has been updated successfully other than time.sleep in code ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to determine if/when the index is up2date. You could make the query a `keys_only` one and then retrieve the actual content of the entities form the query results via key lookups (which are always consistent) and check the `isUsed` actual values.

Comment: You mean `key = SignupTokens.gql(..).get(keys_only=True)` and `ndb.Key(key).get()` ?

Comment: Almost. The query gets you a list of keys, not a key. Then do either `key.get()` for each key or, more efficient, `ndb.get_multi(keys)` (up to 500 keys at a time).

Comment: I tried like `keys = self.query(ndb.AND(self.isUsed == False, self.email == email)).fetch(keys_only=True)` and `obj = keys[0].get()` still it returns sometime older result.

Comment: I'd ask that as a separate question, probably with an mcve. You may need transactions. Maybe go through https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan suggested this is most likely not an `ndb` caching problem. It is the problem caused when you are reading and writing the same entity group continuously. This is a datastore behavior which is basically caused due to ***[datastore contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention?csw=1)*** and ***[eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#nosql-and-eventual-consistency)***.

There are certain ways you can avoid this situation.

- Query using `key`. Whenever you try to read an object via its key it is `strongly consistent`. So, In your case, I would suggest to store the key of the object you are updating, if possible and then read it and perform the operations you want.
- Another approach would be to use NDB Asynchronous Operations. See related ***[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async)*** here.
- You can try to provide a delay which could help you but the delay should be provided in such a way that it is sufficient for the object to get updated.

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Comment: It can happen even if it's a single write, without any contention. Seen often in web apps with pages that use a query inside the GET handler, modify the properties used in those queries inside the POST handler, followed by redirection to the same URL - the next GET request often fails to see the change done in the previous POST request.

Comment: True that @DanCornilescu. It happens a lot in multiple requests too.